when downloading vscode it doesnt allow me to click agree to the terms and condition in vscode and i dont know why, in the pop up installer
when downloading vscode it doesnt let me accept the terms and conditions, like clicking agree to the terms and conditions doesnt do anything, like it doesnt let me click it. i have had vscode 3 days ago and i unistalled it because i was doing something and now i cant download it again.
i try deleting temparary files from %temp% and i have tried to check compabalilty and that isnt the problem either and i tried to run as adminstator with the system installer for vscode and that didnt work, and i have a linux extension on my folder for docker and but chatgpt said that maybe that isnt the problem i dont know what the problem is. and that is what i tried.
okay i found out that, that this problem also occurs when trying to install revo installer because i tried clicking okay after choosing the language and it doesnt register when i click "okay" to continue. so maybe the problem is that i cant install any programs or something, because i was able to redownload python with ease.
